# Flash messages appearing twice in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, flash, twitter-bootstrap

My flash messages are appearing twice and my web research tells me this is due to render and redirect displaying the messages.  I think I need to use flash.now[] or flash[] somewhere to sort this but I can't work out where it needs to go

guidelines_controller.rb

```
def update
  @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @guideline.update_attributes(params[:guideline])
      @guideline.update_attribute(:updated_by, current_user.id)
      format.html { redirect_to @guideline, notice: 'Guideline was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "show" }
      format.json { render json: @guideline.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

layouts/application.html.erb

```
<div class="container">

    <% flash.each do |type, message| %>

        <div class="alert <%= flash_class type %>">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
            <%= message %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

application_helper.rb

def flash_class(type)
  case type
  when :alert
    "alert-error"
  when :notice
    "alert-success"
  else
    ""
  end
end
```

guideline_controller.rb

```
def show
    @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])
    if @guideline.updated_by
     @updated = User.find(@guideline.updated_by).profile_name
   end

      if User.find(@guideline.user_id)
     @created = User.find(@guideline.user_id).profile_name
      end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @guideline }

    end
  end
```

Comment: try fixing that `<% end %>` call there before the `div`. I don't see any issue with your controller code.  I also don't think you need to use `flash.discard`

Comment: have edited as above (is that what you meant?) but the same issue is happening.

Comment: nope. you need to close the div first before the loop. try to indent your code properly so it matches open and closing tags/code

Comment: sorry, I didn't put my edit in correctly - I have edited it (now corrected above) but still no joy

Comment: what does your your guideline show action look like? I assume you are making a html request when you see this problem?

Comment: thanks, have added the show action above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this in order to save some lines of code, and display the messages just once:

```
<%- if flash.any? %>
  <%- flash.keys.each do |flash_key| %>
    <%- next if flash_key.to_s == 'timedout' %>
    <div class="alert-message <%= flash_key %>">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#"> x</a>
      <%= flash.discard(flash_key) %>
    </div>
  <%- end %>
<%- end %>
```

By using flash.discard, you show the flash message an avoid rendering twice

Comment: thanks - I have added that to my application layout (instead of what is above).  Now it's still displaying twice but without the bootstrap styline (which was on one of them only)...any ideas why that might be happening?

Comment: Its annoying that even discarding the flash message, you get the flash being displayed twice. What if you put a <%= debug flash %> before showing the flash, to see if you have duplicated flash messages? That may be the issue.

Comment: Just before the <%- if flash.any? %> of before the flash.each, the <%= debug @flash %> will just display the content of the flash. It would be better if you can use a breakpoint, and in that case you can check the content of the flash by yourself and not having to render it to the screen.

Comment: it just displays --- ... and then underneath says the 'success message' twice.

Comment: If you go into the stackoverflow chat I may be able to help you: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails

Comment: Thanks to @rorra who pain-stakingly went through my code we found an extra flash message displaying on the show view.  Deleted that and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just putting this here for anyone else having trouble.

I had flash messages appearing twice because I had something in `application.html.erb` telling my app to display flash messages, but I had previously generated views with `rails generate scaffold posts` etc, so that had automatically added the flash messages to all the views.

So the solution was to remove them from the views.

[Here](https://guides.railsgirls.com/devise)'s a great tutorial that demonstrates removal for just one model/view

So basically, if you have something like this in your `application.html.erb`:

```
<% if notice %>
  <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<% if alert %>
  <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>
```

Then simply remove the equivalent from each of the views. I.e. remove this line from the top of each view

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue and also due to another call of `<%= render 'shared/alerts' %>` later after my check for `flash`. I liked @rorra's idea of doing a `flash_key`. But here in the year 2020, it wasn't working as @tessad stated. It would show the message, but not format in bootstrap correctly.

I was able to change their code to work with BootStrap 4. It even dismisses as it is supposed to. The three things that needed to change were all dealing with the class of the div used to display the flash notice.

```
<div class="alert-message <%= flash_key %>">
```

`alert-message` becomes just `alert`, and the `flash_key` has to have `alert-` before it.

```
<div class="alert alert-<%= flash_key %>">
```

The last thing is I was sending it to the view from the controller as `flash[:notice]`, which is not a recognized bootstrap alert. When I changed it to `flash[:warning]` it showed up correctly.

Here is the final code that worked for me. Putting it here in case anyone needs it now 7 years after the initial answer was given.

```
<div id="container">
<%- if flash.any? %>
  <%- flash.keys.each do |flash_key| %>
    <%- next if flash_key.to_s == 'timedout' %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= flash_key %>">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#"> x</a>
      <%= flash.discard(flash_key) %>
    </div>
  <%- end %>
<%- end %>
</div>
```

Comment: For current BootStrap alert types go here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/

primary, secondary, success, danger, warning, info, light and dark